# With Realm, should I use a List object or Results object as the data source for a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, realm-mobile-platform

There are at least 2 main collection types used in [Realm](https://realm.io/):

1. [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.0.2/api/Classes/List.html)
2. [Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.0.2/api/Classes/Results.html)

The relevant description from the documentation on a `Results` object says:

> Results is an auto-updating container type in Realm returned from
>   object queries.

Because I want my `UITableView` to respond to any changes on the Realm Object Server, I really think I want my `UITableView` to be backed by a `Results` object. In fact, I think I would always want a `Results` object to back my UI for this reason. This is only reinforced by the description of a `List` object in the documentation:

> List is the container type in Realm used to define to-many
>   relationships.

Sure seems like a `List` is focused on data modeling... So, being new to Realm and just reading the API, I'm thinking the answer is to use the `Results` object, but the [tutorial (Step 5)](https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/example-app/cocoa/) uses the `List` object while the [RealmExamples](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/TableView/TableViewController.swift) sample code uses `Results`.

What am I missing? Should I be using `List` objects to back my `UITableViews`? If so, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use a `List` if one already exists that closely matches what you want to display in your table view, otherwise use a `Results`.

If the data represented by a `List` that's already stored in your Realm corresponds to what you want to display in your table view, you should certainly use that to back it. Lists have an interesting property in that they are implicitly ordered, which can sometimes be helpful, like in the tutorial you linked to above, where a user can *reorder* tasks.

`Results` contain the *results* of a query in Realm. Running this query typically has a higher runtime overhead than accessing a `List`, by how much depends on the complexity of the query and the number of items in the Realm.

That being said, mutating a `List` has performance implications too since it's writing to the file in an atomic fashion. So if this is something that will be changing frequently, a `Results` is likely a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Results<> as the Results is auto updating to back your UITableView. List can be used to link child models in a Realm model. where as Results is used to query the Realm Objects and you should add a Realm Notification Token so you know when the Results are updated and take necessary action (reload table view etc.) Look here for realm notifications: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications

P.S. The data in that example is just static and no changes are observed

Comment: Both List and Results are auto-updating collections.